# Run python script with argparse in another script

Tags: python, import, module, argparse

I have a python script which uses some input parameters via argparse.

something like this:

```
**hello.py**

import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-n", "--name", required=True, help="name of the user")
arguments = parser.parse_args()
print(f'Hello, {arguments.name}')
```

I wonder if this could be ran out in another .py script.

```
**another.py**

names = ['Lu', 'Li', 'La']
for name in names: 
    import hello.py -n name #this is how to run script from console
```

Is there any tricky code for this idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can set by default to parse from environment variables.

```
**hello.py**

import argparse
from os import environ
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-n", "--name", required=True, help="name of the user", default=environ.get("BAR"))
arguments = parser.parse_args()
print(f'Hello, {arguments.name}')
```

And then modify the environment variables.

```
**another.py**
from os import environ
names = ['Lu', 'Li', 'La']
for name in names:
    environ["BAR"] = name
    import hello.py
```